# Azure REST API call is authenticated, but not authorized, can't select services

Tags: rest, azure, authorization, azure-hdinsight

I need to create a script that will make calls to the Azure HDInsight REST API programatically, either periodically from a cron job or after it's initiated by a user.

I followed the instructions on [Service to service calls using client credentials - First case: Access token request with a shared secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret) page in the Azure documentation, I registered a new application with "Native" type and I can make calls to the `/token` endpoint to get the token using my client secret to run my script *(I read the Azure docs for hours and this looked like the right approach, but wasn't easy to understand everything, so I might be mistaken)*.

Unfortunately, as I tried making REST API calls, I realized, that I'm authenticated, but not authorized to make these calls, I got `403 Forbidden` (what Microsoft calls `AuthorizationFailed`).

```
{'code': 'AuthorizationFailed',
 'message': "The client 'CLIENT' with object id 'OBJ' does not 
    have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.HDInsight/...' over scope        
    '/subscriptions/SUBID/resourceGroups/RESGR/providers/Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/CLUSTER'."
}
```

**Where can I authorize my application to be able to make the requests I want it to make?**

I went to the Azure Portal

```
Active Directory
    => App registrations => (Select my app)
    => API Access/Required permissions
    => (+ button, Add API Access) => 1. Select an API
```

At this point, it seems like I can't select the service I likely need, there are services that I can't select. For example, when I type Azure in the search bar, the options are not active, I can't select them.

[image]

I already tried opening `My permissions => Resource Provider Status` and registered everything I thought could be necessary.

My directory role is `User` and I doubt I could change it.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications

Comment: Let me know if this works I will brief it as a response

Comment: If you can't see any selectable service in AAD to add permission to your app this would mean you do not have sufficient rights.

Your application should have given correct permission of services and after assigning the permission you would need to grant them.

REST réponse message seems to be suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your application should not be registered as "native" when you use the client credentials flow. The client credentials flow is used by confidential client applications where the credentials can be stored securely such as a web app or service running on a secure server. A "native" client application is a public client which cannot store credentials in a secure way.

As for accessing the HDInsight service, this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-create-non-interactive-authentication-dotnet-applications) may help your app with the right set up.